# Как выбрать записи с одинаковыми значениями столбцов?

Tags: sql

Нашел некоторые варианты, но ничего не подошло. 
предположим у нас табличка

```
id a b
1  2 3
2  1 2
3  2 3
4  1 2
5  7 4
6  9 6
7  2 6
```

значения могут быть любые.
Нужно выбрать повторяющиеся записи, если запись с а,b повторяется больше 1 раза, выдать в результате. 
Sql результат будет следующий:

```
id a b
1  2 3
3  2 3
2  1 2
4  1 2
```

Comment: можете словесно пояснить логику выборки?

Comment: выбрать повторяющиеся записи, если запись с а,b повторяется больше 1 раза, выдать в результате. В вопросе наглядно показано как это работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Группируем записи по полям a и b и применяем [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), чтобы количество записей в группе было больше 1.

```
CREATE TABLE table2
(
  [id] int, 
  [a] int,
  [b] int 
);

INSERT INTO table2
(
  [id], 
  [a],
  [b]
  )
VALUES
    (1, 2, 3),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 3),
    (4, 1, 2),
    (5, 7, 4),
    (6, 9, 6),
    (7, 2, 6)
    ;


SELECT t1.* from table2 as t1
join
(
  SELECT A,B from table2
  group BY [A],[B]
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) > 1
) t2 on t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
```

Пример работы: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/234c7/9

Comment: это почти работает. только возвращает НЕ ВСЕ одинаковые значение, а те одинаковые что находи, возвращает больше одного раза, плюс вернуло 1 ряд с неповторяющимися значениями. более точнее таблица выглядит так:
(1-2)(5-3)(4-6)(1 -2)(7 -7) (4 -6)(5 -3) (9 -4)(4 -6). вернуть должно (1--2) - 2 ряда и (4-6) 2 ряда

Comment: @DimaRashevskiy, он возвращает то, что вам нужно. У меня вывод совпадает точно с вашим, только в другом порядке. Если требуется сортировка, то можно прикрутить. Сейчас в sqlfiddle загоню

Comment: добавил ссылку на sqlfiddle с примером работы

Comment: спасибо, если не сложно посмотрите, пожалуйста, правку

Comment: что значит  (5-3) и (5 -3) то разные записи? что вообще значат скобки. Чему равно a и b в этом случае. Сформулируйте пжлста задачу должным образом

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77387/discussion-between-dima-rashevskiy-and-alexcei-shmakov).

Comment: я внес изменения.

Comment: вы меня спали! единственное что очень тоже важно это то что если ряд повторяется дважды, то он и выводится дважды. я имею ввиду: у нас есть 2 одинаковых ряда с одинаковыми значениями, они оба выводятся. НО также есть два одинаковых ряда с одним именем (или id если хотите), такой ряд надо выводить 1 раз. К примеру ряд (name=a x =1 y =2) повторяется дважды, тогда его надо вывести 1 раз. а если ряд с одинакомыми  значениями но разным именем, то выводим все ряды такого типа

Comment: в вашем примере 5-3 ни разу не выводилось с одинаковым id.

Comment: ну если предположить что в таблице есть такие 2 записи (name=a a =1 b =2) , то они обе выведутся. Если запись совпадает по всем 3 пунктам, она должна выводиться 1 раз

Answer (score 1):

Решал задачу в первоначальной в постановке.

```
with cte as
(select * from t where id<=4),
idt as (select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn from cte),
at as (select a, row_number() over(order by a desc) rn from cte),
bt as (select b, row_number() over(order by b desc) rn from cte)
select id,a,b from idt join at on idt.rn=at.rn
join bt on idt.rn=bt.rn
```

Comment: можете объяснить ?  id<=4 это зачем вообще? что такое cte, idt, bt

Comment: Я решал задачу при неопределенных условиях, потому ограничил id, как в ожидаемом результате. cte и проч. - это CTE - уже поддерживается и MySQL.